# How to use fontfamily directly from web url in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to apply fontfamily directly from web URL without downloading it to local machine.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You mean the user do not need install the font or not download the font at all?

Comment: exactly, the url should fetch the fantfamily so that i can use it

Comment: You will have to download the font anyway(temporarily),but the user need not install it.

Comment: by giving the absolute path of the .ttf on local machine my requirement is fulfilled but i wonder if url path of file on local machine is working then why not web url. What i refer is (http://googlefontdirectory.googlecode.com/hg/ofl/missfajardose/MissFajardose-Regular.ttf) url.